# Spin The Wheel With Touch Inputs in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in unity So, I wanted to Make A Fortune Wheel But Instead of Rotating it with a button I want Like, the speed of its spinning will depend on how fast I touch n' dragged the wheel itself.

If I flick/rotate it very fast, the wheel would go spinning faster.

If I only moved it slowly, then it would barely spin at all. Just like what would happen if you spin a wheel like in Wheel of Fortune in real life.

Thanks

Comment: What you can measure is the distance between the first touch and when the drag finishes. You can use Input.GetTouch() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Touch control object rotation and zoom in Unity.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.IO;

public class ScaleAndRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Touch oldTouch1; //Last touch point 1 (finger 1)
  private Touch oldTouch2; //Last touch point 2 (finger 2)

void Start()
{

}
  



void Update() {

    // no touch
    if ( Input. touchCount <= 0 ){
        return;
    }

    //Single touch, rotate horizontally up and down
    if( 1 == Input.touchCount ){
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 deltaPos = touch.deltaPosition;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * deltaPos.x , Space.World);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * deltaPos.y , Space.World);
    }

    //Multi-touch, zoom in and out
    Touch newTouch1 = Input.GetTouch(0);
    Touch newTouch2 = Input.GetTouch(1);
      
    //The second point just started touching the screen, only recording, not processing
    if( newTouch2.phase == TouchPhase.Began ){
        oldTouch2 = newTouch2;
        oldTouch1 = newTouch1;
        return;
    }
      
    //Calculate the distance between the old two points and the distance between the new two points. When it becomes larger, you need to enlarge the model, and when it becomes smaller, you need to zoom the model.
    float oldDistance = Vector2.Distance(oldTouch1.position, oldTouch2.position);
    float newDistance = Vector2.Distance(newTouch1.position, newTouch2.position);

    //The difference between the two distances, positive means zoom in gesture, negative means zoom out gesture
    float offset = newDistance - oldDistance;

    //Amplification factor, one pixel is calculated by 0.01 times (100 can be adjusted)
    float scaleFactor = offset / 100f;
    Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
    Vector3 scale = new Vector3(localScale.x + scaleFactor,
                                localScale.y + scaleFactor,
                                localScale.z + scaleFactor);

    //Minimum zoom to 0.3 times
    if (scale.x > 0.3f && scale.y > 0.3f && scale.z > 0.3f) {
        transform.localScale = scale;
    }

    //Remember the latest touch point and use it next time
    oldTouch1 = newTouch1;
    oldTouch2 = newTouch2;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps you.